# Product engineer

Tags: mechanical-engineering

What thickness of stainless steel and grade will I need for a step cover that is 30.25" by 14".  One long side will have a1" bend lip and the three other sides will rest on a solid flat surface.

Comment: Missing the max load applied and showing what you have done so far.

Comment: Max load would be 200 pounds.

Comment: Still missing what you have done so far... Also point load, footprint or spread evenly?

Comment: It will be a plate that covers the step well with the load would be a person stepping on the cover.  Need to figure the deflection on this surface from a single load point in the center of the plate.  Need to know if 1/8" is correct thickness or do I need thicker?  Want stainless for heavy wear and long life.

Comment: Have you ever looked at a grille over a hole that people step on?

Comment: This is an custom size and need to keep light weight and easy to lift up and out of the way.  Have not been able to find steel guides on strength of flat stainless steels.  Just trying to find out if 1/8" is what will work or do I need thicker.